# Why would I not choose the Team Offer with the highest bonus?

Tags: dirt-3

Before every race, you get to choose your Team (or rather, your car).
Different cars offer different reputation bonuses for completing certain objectives during the race.

But I, rather boringly, am constantly drawn to the team with the highest Objective Bonus.

Is there any reason (other than personal preference and variety) not to pick the highest team bonus?

The stat differences seem rather minor and so far I haven't had much difficulty completing the objectives, but I'm fairly early in the game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason why you should not choose the team which offers high rep. Also it was added for replay-ability because once you complete a race with a particular team then you can't get the rep again but if you play the race with other team then you can again get the rep for objectives.

As you are early in the game, that is why you are getting this question. After ample amount of rep, you'll get teams which are not on top but will provide better rep because of the bonus objectives which would be easier to complete in that particular race.